# Symfony 5 Cannot autowire argument $Driver for a dynamic database connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sqlsrv

I am currently facing a problem, I explain myself. For my project I'm trying to make a dynamic connection to a database (I have 2 virtual machines with a different IP but with the same identifiers and tables with MSSQL database engine (SQLSRV)).

I try something like this ->

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver;
 /**
 * @Route("/testconnection", name="test_connect")
 */
public function testConnection(Driver $Driver){

    $connectionParams = array(
        'dbname' => 'job',
        'user' => 'sa',
        'password' => 'Lasernet@2020',
        'host' => '192.168.1.34',
        'driver' => 'pdo_sqlsrv',
    );

    $conn = $Driver->connect($connectionParams);
    dd($conn);
}
```

Error message

**Cannot autowire argument $Driver of "App\Controller\HomeController:testConnection()": it references class "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver" but no such services exists.**

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRbnP.png)

But the problem is that Symfony sends me back an error that I find hard to solve/understand.
If someone has a solution to my problem/success to make a dynamic connection to databases.

If you need more information tell me.

Comment: Consider copy/pasting the relevant portions of your error message into your question.

Comment: Please avoid adding follow-up question to your existing question. If you've marked it as resolved, then post a new question with the new error.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it. No such service exists.
You must define the `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver` class as a symfony service in your `public/services.yaml` to autowire it.

Update your `public/services.yaml` with:

```yaml
services:
    
    Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver:
        autowire: true
```

But why you will autowire this class? The same behaviour you can get with

```php
public function testConnection(){
    $Driver = new Driver();
    $connectionParams = array(
        'dbname' => 'job',
        'user' => 'sa',
        'password' => 'Lasernet@2020',
        'host' => '192.168.1.34',
        'driver' => 'pdo_sqlsrv',
    );

    $conn = $Driver->connect($connectionParams);
    dd($conn);
}
```

And if you have no really dynamic values in your connection params like `$connectionParams['dbname'] = 'sqldb'.$i`, better to use the doctrine dbal config and get the connection with `$this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('name');` in your controller.

[Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, this is a monitoring application that could allow you to administer dozens of different databases but always with the same structure (Tables, fields). When I want to connect to a database the information entered is stored in a database (a parameter database to the application) and it is then from the connection data entered in the database that I connect to an instance.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)